# Creating a quality score column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am working with a dataframe in pandas which looks something like this

```
ID    Color    Size      Shape
1     Blue     Small     Triangle
2     Red      Medium    Square
3     Yellow   Large     Circle
```

I would like to compare each row to a list of data and create a new score column that counts the number of times each row matches the list.

Example [Red, Medium, Circle] would yield the following dataframe.

```
ID    Color    Size      Shape      Score
1     Blue     Small     Triangle     0
2     Red      Medium    Square       2
3     Yellow   Large     Circle       1
```

Ideally I would like the ability to create multiple score columns to check against multiple lists.

Answer (score 2):

Using `isin` for data.frame

```
l=['Red', 'Medium', 'Circle']
df['score']=df.isin(l).sum(1)
df
Out[404]: 
   ID   Color    Size     Shape  score
0   1    Blue   Small  Triangle      0
1   2     Red  Medium    Square      2
2   3  Yellow   Large    Circle      1
```

Comment: Would it be possible to weight the different categories. For example color having a score of 1, and size having a score of 10, and shape having a score of 15?